# Linq Multiple Joins - Too many results

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling to get a sql statement converted into Linq.

I am getting too many results and cannot work out what the correct syntax should be.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT        
    Client_Details_Legacy.FullName, 
    Client_Details_Legacy.AddressLine1, 
    Client_Details_Legacy.AddressLine2, 
    Client_Details_Legacy.AddressLine3, 
    Policy_Property.PolicyNumber, 
    Policy_Property.CoverTo, 
    Clients.Id
FROM            
    Clients 
    INNER JOIN Policy_Property 
        ON Clients.Id = Policy_Property.Client_Id 
    INNER JOIN Client_Details_Legacy 
        ON Clients.Client_Details_Legacy_Id = Client_Details_Legacy.Id
WHERE        
    (Policy_Property.CoverTo >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (Policy_Property.CoverTo <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
ORDER BY 
    Clients.Id
```

This is as close as I have managed to get with my Linq statement but it's returning more rows than it should be.

I suspect it's something to do with joins but I just cannot seem to get the correct syntax:

```
var query = from clients in db.Clients
                        .Include("Client_Details_Legacy")
                        .Include("Policies_Property")
            where clients.Client_Details_Legacy.Country.Code == countryCode 
                  && clients.Policies_Property.Any(x => x.CoverTo >= CoverToStart 
                                                        && x.CoverTo <= CoverToEnd)
            select clients;

return query.ToList();
```

This is my model...

```
public class Client 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClientNumber_Legacy { get; set; }
    [Index]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClientNuber_Websure { get; set; }
    public Client_Details_Enhanced Client_Details_Enhanced { get; set; }
    public Client_Details_Legacy Client_Details_Legacy { get; set; }
    public Client_Details_Websure Client_Details_Websure { get; set; }
    public List<Policy_Motor> Policies_Motors { get; set; }
    public List<Policy_Property> Policies_Property { get; set; }
}

public class Policy_Property 
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public Policy_Property_Details_Legacy Policy_Property_Details_Legacy { get; set; }
    public Policy_Property_Details_Enhanced Policy_Property_Details_Enhanced { get; set; }
    public DateTime CoverFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime CoverTo { get; set; }
    public List<Insured_Property> Insured_Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Client_Details_Legacy 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ws_lookup_ClientType ClientType { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public ws_lookup_Title Title { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string NationalIdNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Address Line 1")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Line 2")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Line 3")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Line 4")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Country")]
    public ws_lookup_Country Country { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Parish")]
    public ws_lookup_Parish Parish { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Home Telephone Number")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string HomeTelephoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Work Telephone Number")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string WorkTelephoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Gender")]
    public ws_lookup_Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Loyalty Card")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LoyaltyCard { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Occupation")]
    public ws_lookup_Occupation Occupation { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Why is there a country code in the linq attempt, but not in the original sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is that your query returns certain data whereas you are trying to return specific clients.  But that won't work as a client is associated with multiple policies, but you are only interested in particular policies.  The following should give the same results as your SQL.

```
var query = from client in db.Clients
            from policy in client.Policies_Property
            where policy.CovertTo >= ConvertToStart && policy.ConverTo <= ConverToEnd
                  && client.Client_Details_Legacy != null
            select new
            {
                client.Client_Details_Legacy.FullName, 
                client.Client_Details_Legacy.AddressLine1, 
                client.Client_Details_Legacy.AddressLine2, 
                client.Client_Details_Legacy.AddressLine3, 
                policy.PolicyNumber, 
                policy.CoverTo, 
                client.Id
            };
```

Note I left out the `client.Client_Details_Legacy.Country.Code == countryCode` as that was not present in your SQL.

Comment: if a Client has no matching ClientDetailLegacy - in the original it would be filtered, but would not be filtered as I read this code..

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement can be easily translated into LINQ this way:

```
var query = from clients in db.Clients
                        join cdl in db.Client_Details_Legacy on cdl.Id = clients.Client_Details_Legacy_Id
                        join pp in db.Policies_Property on pp.Client_Id = clients.Id
            where pp.CoverTo >= CoverToStart && pp.CoverTo <= CoverToEnd
            select new { 
                FullName = cdl.FullName, 
                AddressLine1 = cdl.AddressLine1, 
                AddressLine2 = cdl.AddressLine2, 
                AddressLine3 = cdl.AddressLine3, 
                PolicyNumber = pp.PolicyNumber,
                CoverTo = pp.CoverTo,
                Id = clients.Id
                };
return query.OrderBy(q => q.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: I recommend that you read [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)

Comment: Well, using navigation properties is nothing new, but also not necessarily the better way to translate the SQL query. Imagine the entities do not have the navigation properties, for whatever reason, so how do you make the LINQ query then?

Comment: Then you would use join, but the point is that Navigation properties are preferable if present as they are in this case.

Comment: So, then join will work regardless of the navigation properties are present or not. Until the OP does not explicitly specifiy there are navigation properties, I'd prefer to use standard, always working way to build the LINQ query from the SQL one. And of course the navigation properties are the preferable/easier way to construct joins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line here is the issue:

```
clients.Policies_Property.Any(x => x.CoverTo >= CoverToStart && x.CoverTo <= CoverToEnd)
```

The use of `Any` will return all records if 1 is satisfied, instead of just returning the rows that satisfy that clause.

> Enumerable.Any : Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

Without having the means to see the data or test, you could try...

```
where clients.Client_Details_Legacy.Country.Code == countryCode 
                 && (clients.Policies_Property.CoverTo >= CoverToStart &&
                    clients.Policies_Property.CoverTo <= CoverToEnd)
```

Comment: I agree that's the problem, but you haven't put forth a solution, so this would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @juharr, I was just typing it up :)

Comment: `Policies_Property` is a `List<Policy_Property>` so it will not have a `CovertTo` property.